# MySQL 1054 Unknown column 'Array'

Tags: joomla

I am using Joomla 3.1 and in the code there is an error 1054 Unknown column 'Array' Please help me fix it.

```
protected function getOptions()
{
    // Initialize variables.
    $options = array();

    $varname = (string) $this->element['varname'];
    $project_id = JFactory::getApplication()->input->get($varname);
    if (is_array($project_id)) {
        $project_id = $project_id[0];
    }

    if ($project_id)
    {
        $db = JFactory::getDbo();
        $query = $db->getQuery(true);

        $query->select('id AS value');
        $query->select('CASE LENGTH(name) when 0 then CONCAT('.$db->Quote(JText::_('COM_JOOMLEAGUE_GLOBAL_MATCHDAY_NAME')). ', " ", id) else name END as text ');
        $query->from('#__joomleague_round ');
        $query->where('project_id = '.$project_id);
        $query->order('roundcode');
        $db->setQuery($query);
        $options = $db->loadObjectList();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, `$project_id[0]` still holds an array. Since I don't know where `$this->element['varname']` is coming from, it's hard to say what you're variable holds :-)

Also just as a note: You probably should filter the input before using it in the query, especially if you're using it unescaped like in your example. Force it to a number using `(int)` at least.

To dump some variable contents, I can recommend JDump. It's a non-commercial extension available on JED (http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/miscellaneous/development/1509).

Comment: thanks for the reply. but for me it is difficult option I am a newbie. If possible, I provided a complete file and all you need to solve the error.